# Reading xml value inside tag from class with Xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml, console, console-application

I have some issues about read a xml file. I have to fill xml tag as a class properties. Is there a way to get to solve this problem?

I looked every xml serialization article. When I try to run my code, I got null value from class

Here is my Program.cs

```
    Log lg = new Log();
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Logs\Workflow User 
  Functions\2019\05\15\01.xml");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.HasAttributes && lg.date !=null && lg.datetime !=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute(lg.date) + 
   reader.GetAttribute(lg.datetime));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And my Log.cs

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName ="date")]
public string date { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "datetime")]
public string datetime { get; set; }
```

Also my xml file which I try to get attribute value

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Logs version="1" appname="Workflow User Functions" id="fed9fc29-f6bf-4814-8401-f8742ea0ceef" date="15/30/2019 01">
<Log id="" logtype="Error" datetime="30:52" user="workflow" logname="ScheduledJobs.fnExecute_Execute">Process Id : 69705
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code for the `Log` class - i.e. a [mcve]?  How are `lg.date` and `lg.datetime`, and why would they be non-null immediately after you allocated `lg`?

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. If I upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com I get an error, **Errors in the XML document: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.**

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof), i.e. `reader.GetAttribute(nameof(lg.date)) && reader.GetAttribute(nameof(lg.datetime))` ?  In this case you would be searching the XML for for attributes with the same name, not the same value, as the `date` and `datetime` members.  (Also, `nameof()` never returns `null`, so remove `&& lg.date !=null && lg.datetime !=null`.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your all responses.

I did a few changes and then it works.

Program.cs;

```
                          List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();
                  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Logs\Workflow User 
                          Functions\2019\03\05\13.xml");
                  reader.MoveToContent();
                     while (reader.Read())
      {
      if (reader.HasAttributes)
      {
      var lg = new Log
      {
        date = reader.GetAttribute("date"),
        datetime = reader.GetAttribute("datetime")
      };
    logs.Add(lg);

    Console.WriteLine($"{lg.date} {lg.datetime}");
}
```

}
            Console.ReadLine();